# Xamarin forms: System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a grouped listview in my project. When I try to add the `ItemSelected` event for the listview I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

**My Code**

**XAML:**

```
<ListView
  ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
            //header label
                <Label/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        BackgroundColor="#f9f9f9"
                        Orientation="Vertical">

                        //Items
                    </StackLayout>

                        <Label Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Footer>
        <Label/>
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

**Viewmodel**

```
public ObservableCollection<EventsHB> AllItems
{
    get
    {
        return _allItems;
    }
    set
    {
        _allItems = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AllItems");
    }
}
```

**XAML.CS**

```
MyEventsListview.ItemSelected += (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    var selectedItem = (EventsHB) e.SelectedItem;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        //loading the next page
    }
    MyEventsListview.SelectedItem = null;
};
```

Comment: Can you see in debugger what `SelectedItem` is?

Comment: @Miamy At that line app breaks with this exception

Comment: So you should to put a breakpoint on this line and see the variable value

Comment: @Miamy Got the solution, I have added it as my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got solution from my [XF thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/406514#Comment_406514).

This is because EventsHB is your group item but the selected item is a part of your group item you can't cast it to EventsHB.
i.e.

```
// Your EventsHB looks like
public class EventsHB : ObservableCollection<Model>
{
   public string Title { set; get; }
}
```

Then the type of the selected item is Model.